# "Deprecated: mysql_connect()" error when installing Roots Bedrock

Tags: installation

I'm trying to install [Roots Bedrock](https://github.com/roots/bedrock) on my local Windows 7 workstation, and I fail miserably.

This is the procedure I've been doing:

1. Cloned the Bedrock project
2. Copied its content in my (empty) "c:/my-project/wordpress" project directory
3. Opened a terminal, cd-ed to "c:/my-project/wordpress", and executed `composer install`. All good.
4. Copied "c:/my-project/wordpress/.env.example" to "c:/my-project/wordpress/.env", and edited it to the following:

   ```
   DB_NAME=<MY_WP_DB>
   DB_USER=root
   DB_PASSWORD=<PASSWORD_FOR_ROOT>
   DB_HOST=localhost

   WP_ENV=development
   WP_HOME=http://localhost
   WP_SITEURL=http://localhost/wp
   ```
5. Updated the Apache HTTPD config file to:

   ```
   DocumentRoot "c:/my-project/wordpress/web"
   <Directory "c:/my-project/wordpress/web">
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride FileInfo
       Require all granted
   </Directory>
   ```
6. Started Apache HTTPD server
7. In my browser, accessed "http://localhost/wp/wp-admin"
8. Got error "Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in C:\Pro\redesigned-cruited.com-frontend\wordpress\web\wp\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1482"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is your PHP version? Does it have mysqli driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a Bedrock issue, but an issue with your local install.

Your local install probably uses the old `php_mysql` extension, instead of the modern `php_mysqli`.

You should probable update your local environment.

This is where the change landed in WordPress codebase (17 months ago)

https://core.trac.wordpress.org/changeset/27935

Comment: Weird that I didn't see this error when installing vanilla Wordpress.